# Finding Value of specified cell address defined in CSV file

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datagridview, datatable

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("A");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("B");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("C");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("D");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("E");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("F");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("H");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("I");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("J");
            string filePath = @"data.csv";
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string[] totalData = new string[File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length];
            totalData = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                totalData = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                dataTable.Rows.Add(totalData[0], totalData[1], totalData[2], totalData[3], totalData[4]
                    , totalData[5], totalData[6], totalData[7], totalData[8]);
            }

            DataView dv = new DataView(dataTable);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

        }

    }
```

I have established one text box so that the user writes the input as for example "A3" and I have another label that will produce  the result of that input as "405" I mean like an Excel Program..How can I do that with my defined datatable?
[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [photobox.com](https://img2.brain3.photobox.com/94862614b0b3b4391911d206023823fa9e8c2c76cd7b89714f809d319a067ae9a659bb1e.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What have you tried to achive that? If yiu allready have your data read, just take the third line and chose it´s first entry. What´s the problem?

Comment: I  don't how to identify row index according to specified column. I don't have to show data on datagridview. I just showed it to explain what is the main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give a algo to complete it.

1. Split your consistent input in an array which is Alphabet+numeric
2. Take first value as an column name and second is row index so you will get your value like :

> `string fieldName = "A";   int fieldRow = 3;  int myval = 0;`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Table.Rows.Count-1; i++) //Looping through rows
    {
         if (fieldRow == i) 
         {
                myval = Table.Rows[i]["fieldName"]; //Getting my field value
                break;
          }

    }
```

Comment: I had to remove the double quotes for "fieldName". Thank you.